# Cannot set the webhook of my Telegram Bot

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I set the webhook of my Telegram Bot and it seems to work fine, but the bot doesn't reply when I try to write him. The code of the file I indicated as webhook is correct (I checked it with getupdates method) and the server where it's hosted has the SSL certificate.

Trying to see the result of the method getWebhookInfo I checked up that the error was ***"Wrong response from the webhook: 410 Gone"***.

Anyone could help me to find out where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to copy the url you received from getWebhookInfo and then POST some valid JSON to it (e.g. on linux with curl, examples here: [Telegram Guide](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks#the-verbose-version)).

WRON RESPONSE FROM WEBHOOK indicates that there is a problem with your web server configuration or something elso on the way in.
"410 Gone" is returned by your webserver, so maybe your .httaccess config is wrong (if using Apachee).